How to ask closed question to be migrated to the site where they are relevant?
For example, How I can ask to migrate this post to worldbuilding stack exchange?

You can flag the question for moderator attention (this would apply to non-closed questions as well). See the FAQ about migration; but it also contains a warning:

If the site isn't in the list of available migration targets, or the question got closed without being migrated, first read the below points and consider if migration is/was really the appropriate action (in many cases, it isn't).

You have to consider not only if the question is on-topic there, but also if the answer you got complies with what the target community expects from an answer.
In many cases, it's better just to re-ask the question (and perhaps link to the one on Bitcoin.SE) and adapt it to the guidelines of the other community.

Tried. declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention while both the answer and the question are acceptable. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213790/is-it-ok-to-post-the-same-question-on-several-stack-exchange-sites#comment688528_213793

I declined the moderator flag the first time, because I didn't think it would be a good fit there, but I see that you have some reputation on that site, so I've migrated it now.

First reaction by worldbuilding users is that it's a bad fit.

@Murch and similar biology question from mine was well received on worldbuilding, so I thought it would be Ok.
